# Unity not reporting errors for custom class called through event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm setting up networking and in doing so, have a basic event system to allow classes to act on packets received. Upon receiving a packet (server side) of client information, I am trying to send back an `Object` containing a game state.

I am able to `Debug.Log` inside all my code totally fine, but in the following function, after the `Debug.Log("Sending Game State");` line, no further code executes.

```
    public static void SendGameState(int connectionID, Color[,] gameState) { // Change to a proper game state
        Debug.Log("Sending Game state");
        ByteBuffer buffer = new ByteBuffer(4);
        buffer.WriteInt32((int)ServerPackets.SGameState);
        buffer.WriteObject(gameState);

        Debug.Log("Sending Game state");
        NetworkConfig.socket.SendDataTo(connectionID, buffer.Data, buffer.Head);

        buffer.Dispose();
    }
```

I don't care what's causing the error I'm only interested in how to get Unity to report it. Obviously I can do manual error catching, but to save time I want it done automatically like Unity normally does

I'm also aware that more details are likely needed for this question to be answered, but I have no idea where to begin and don't have any idea why Unity suddenly stopped reporting errors for only this code (everything else is reported as normal).

Comment: What is `socket.SendDataTo`? If it's a usual socket, you should change its `SendTimeout` property, then a SocketException will be thrown.

Comment: @shingo The error wasn't in that line, the error is with `buffer.WriteObject(gameState);` as `gameState` isn't a serializable object. So that isn't the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UnhandledExceptionHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings-actionOnDotNetUnhandledException.html). Perhaps this logs it.

As for the code, you say the "code following the log Sending Game state", but there are two. Assuming you mean the first, I can see you are trying to allocate a byte buffer of 4 bytes. Then you call a WriteInt32 (4bytes) and then you proceed to write more. That looks like a buffer overflow, which is weird as ByteBuffer seems to imply FlatBuffers and I'd assume they do at least buffer overflow checks, but I can't be sure. The unity fork of flatbuffers generates the lib from cpp and that's the nuget. Can't verify.

Comment: I did manual error logging with a `try-catch` and the error was in the line `buffer.WriteObject(gameState);` as `gameState` wasn't serializable. This is easy to fix, but the problem still remains that I had to manually log the error myself. What do I do with the `UnhandledExceptionHandler`? Is it a setting in the editor I need to turn on?

Comment: It's a setting which tells the app whether to crash or not and whether to produce a crash report or not.